# Hiding parent table row on child textbox length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide table row if asp:Textbox inside that row is empty.

Am I doing it right? Is it even possible like this or i should take different approach?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".TableRow").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var child = el.parent().children(".TexBoxTR").lenght;
    if (child > 0) {
      el.parent().hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="TableRow">
    <td class="tg-yw4l">A</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="tg-yw4la" style="width: 250px">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="274px" ID="textbox2" CssClass="auto-style1 TexBoxTR" Enabled="false"></asp:textbox>
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="274px" ID="textbox3" CssClass="auto-style1" Visible="false"></asp:textbox>
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="274px" ID="textbox4" CssClass="auto-style1" Visible="false"></asp:textbox>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="TableRow">
    <td class="tg-yw4l">A/1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" style="width: 250px">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="274px" ID="textbox5" CssClass="auto-style1 TexBoxTR" Enabled="false"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="111px" ID="textbox6" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-a86t" align="right">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="68px" ID="textbox7" placeholder="0" Enabled="False"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TableRow">
    <td class="tg-yw4l">A/2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" style="width: 250px">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="274px" ID="textbox8" CssClass="auto-style1 TexBoxTR" Enabled="false"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="111px" ID="textbox9" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-a86t" align="right">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="68px" ID="textbox10" placeholder="0" Enabled="False"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TableRow">
    <td class="tg-yw4l">A/3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" style="width: 250px">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="274px" ID="textbox11" CssClass="auto-style1 TexBoxTR" Enabled="false"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="111px" ID="textbox12" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-a86t" align="right">
      <asp:textbox runat="server" Width="68px" ID="textbox13" placeholder="0" Enabled="False"></asp:textbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and post a [mcve] WITHOUT any ASP since this is not an asp question

Comment: Do you want to hide it if all textboxes are empty or just one textbox in the row is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use below code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".TableRow td .TexBoxTR").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I think mine was more elegant :) - And yours can be written `$(this).closest("tr").hide();`

Comment: Indeed it was but you know, political correctness, i don't want to be labeled as racist for rest of my life. Also when i copy pasted your code, everything disappeared.

Comment: Racist? `val()==""` would likely fix my code, but as you did not post a [mcve] I could not test it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to spell `lenght` `length`

But you likely mean this:

```
 $(".TableRow").each(function () {
   $(this).toggle($(this).find(".TexBoxTR").val()==""); // show if not empty
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the text box value length and then find the closest tr like below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".TableRow td .TexBoxTR").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim().length==0) {
            $(this).closest("tr").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".TableRow td .TexBoxTR").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
            $(this).closest(".TableRow").hide();
        }
    });
});
```